# Get Firebase InstanceId from another app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, instanceid

I am writing an Android library that be installed on several external apps. This library will have to receive and send Firebase Message from and to my server.

To do that I need to get a FirebaseInstanceId for the app using my library, however a FirebaseInstanceId usage is restricted to the projectId that spawned the InstanceId. Trying to use the Firebase API with an InstanceId created from an app I do not control return a 403.

I tried to manually create a FirebaseApp, setting the apiKey, appId, etc to the values from my own firebase project, but the instanceId I get from that is always null

Is there a way to get a Firebase InstanceID token I can use to send message to other app with my library?

Answer (score 1):

Aaand I found the answer less than one hour after...

We can use `FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(String authorizedEntity, String scope)` to get a token allowing us to perform firebase operation on another app (ex : set "FCM" in the scope to use the Firebase Cloud Messaging)